# Search strings using regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, find

When I try to use regular expression for finding strings in other strings, it does not work as expected. Here is an example:

```
import re
message = 'I really like beer, but my favourite beer is German beer.'
keywords = ['beer', 'german beer', 'german']

regex = re.compile("|".join(keywords))
regex.findall(message.lower())
```

Result:

```
['beer', 'beer', 'german beer']
```

But the expected result would be:

```
['beer', 'beer', 'german beer', 'german']
```

Another way to do that could be:

```
results = []
for k in keywords:
    regex = re.compile(k)
    for r in regex.findall(message.lower()):
        results.append(r)

['beer', 'beer', 'beer', 'german beer', 'german']
```

It works like I want, but I think it is not the best way to do that. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`re.findall` cannot find overlapping matches. If you want to use regular expressions you will have to create separate expressions and run them in  a loop as in your second example.

Note that your second example can also be shortened to the following, though it's a matter of taste whether you find this more readable:

```
results = [r for k in keywords for r in re.findall(k, message.lower())]
```

Your specific example doesn't require the use of regular expressions. You should avoid using regular expressions if you just want to find fixed strings.

Comment: The questioner doesn't only want to test whether a particular substring is part of a string but he wants all occurrences of a particular substring. In this case, the use of `re.findall()` is the best way to accomplish that. Avoiding regular expressions would make this solution more laborious than necessary.

Comment: Thanks you guys for your replies. Now I know I am using a wrong function (findall), so what do you recommend for find matches, including overlappings?

Comment: @Adrián: Do you need the power of regular expressions or do you just want to find fixed strings?

Comment: I would like to find fixed strings, but I asked about regular expressions because I was thinking it is the best way (optimal way).

Answer (score 6):

`re.findall` is described in http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

"Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string..."

Non-overlapping means that for "german beer" it will not find "german beer" AND "german", because those matches are overlapping.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Omri Barel. What do you recommend for find matches, including overlappings?

Comment: In general you have to do what you've done: one keyword at a time. But for a better solution you'll have to describe what you're really trying to do (i.e. what is the actual situation without simplifying to trivial examples).

Comment: Omri, as I have write in the answer bellow, I asked about regular expressions because I was thinking it is the best and optimal way to do that. The strings fo find will be always fixed (word1|word2|word3...), I mean no complex regex.

Comment: If you have a lot of text to search, it may be worth looking at the Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) which looks for a set of strings simultaneously (including overlapping matches). Otherwise, looking for one string at a time should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

My cleaner (for me) version for your last solution

```
results = []
for key in keywords:
    results.extend(re.findall(key, message, re.IGNORECASE))
```